# How much concrete floor cutting should I expect in this new layout for my basement bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I am assuming that relocating the vanity is the most difficult thing here. The plumbing is copper. Should I continue with copper of connect with plastic PEX.
Below is the old layout. In the old layout, on the top floor there is another toilet for which a very little portion of the drain elbow is visible near the basement ceiling and it possibly runs through the wall that separates the basement vanity from the basement toilet. Could that be so ? (drain running through that wall?
[image]
An this is the new layout

[image]

Comment: The drain probably is running down the wall from the upstairs, as far as how much concrete cutting if any is required you would need to open the walls and see what plumbing is available.

Comment: which wall are you talking about ? The one I am planning to remove and replace with glass, next tot the toilet?

Comment: If the plumbing is in the wall at the location of the new sink you may not have to cut concrete